# Permit to a discord bot to reach messages data of a dirict message discussion

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js and I would like to analyze messages of a DM dicussion using a bot.
I have a simple question, is there a way to reach data of a DM discussion with someone using a bot(giving at the bot the permission to reach the messages).
I'm not sure if this is possible or not, I was thinking at something like a getMessageById or similar, but it's obvious that this would be a massive privacy  problem of the message.

Let me know if is there a way, but I'm quite sure that there isn't one.
Thank you, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Bots can only check the dm between themselves and the user. No dms between two users ofc.

Self bots would be able to but discord patched em I believe.